# PHP: Need one-dimensional array but building multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've written a function to build an array of categories with unlimited recursive child categories.  The issue I'm running into is that it's adding the children categories as nested sub-arrays, so it's a multidimensional array:

[0][0], [0][1], [0][1][0], [0][2]

But I would like it to look like it to be one-dimensional:

[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]

My function:

```
function cat_array($parent, $level){
    global $link;
    $q_cats = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = '$parent' ORDER BY name ASC";
    $r_cats = mysqli_query ($link, $q_cats) or die('Catastrophic failure [Super secret code 95162]');
    $num_cats=mysqli_num_rows($r_cats);
    if($num_cats != 0){
        while ($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($r_cats)) {
            $cat_id = $row_cats['id'];
            $name = $row_cats['name'];
            $safename = $row_cats['safename'];
            $parent = $row_cats['parent'];
            $catcounter = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM links WHERE category = '$cat_id'");
            $catnum = mysqli_fetch_array($catcounter);
            $catcount = number_format($catnum["id"]);

            $cat_array = array("id"=>$cat_id, "name"=>$name, "safename"=>$safename, "parent"=>$parent, "linkcount"=>$catcount, "level"=>$level);

            /* This is supposed to use the function again inside this loop to find the children of the current row */
            $cat_array3[] = cat_array($cat_id, $level+1);

            /* If the child loop isn't empty, merge them. */
            if(!empty($cat_array3)){
                $cat_array4[] = array_merge($cat_array, $cat_array3);
            }

            /* Wiping the temp arrays */
            UNSET($cat_array);
            UNSET($cat_array2);
            UNSET($cat_array3);


        }
        /* Placed inside the count check so it doesn't return anything if nothing found */
        $cat_array = $cat_array4;
        return $cat_array;
    }

}
```

Here's the array it's building:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => ALTERNATOR, BATTERY & CHARGING
            [safename] => alternator-battery-and-charging
            [parent] => 0
            [linkcount] => 0
            [level] => 0
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => ALTERNATOR
                            [safename] => alternator
                            [parent] => 1
                            [linkcount] => 0
                            [level] => 1
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 35
                                            [name] => Loose or Weak Contact at Generator Harness Connector TSB 96-21-4 for 86-93 Bronco
                                            [safename] => loose-or-weak-contact-at-generator-harness-connector-tsb-96-21-4-for-86-93-bronco
                                            [parent] => 3
                                            [linkcount] => 0
                                            [level] => 2
                                            [0] => 
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 36
                                            [name] => No Crank, Low State Of Battery Charge TSB 91-10-8 for 85-91 Bronco, Bronco II, Econoline, F-150-350 Series, Ranger; 86-91 Aerostar; 88-91 F Super Duty, F47, F-53, F-59; 91 Explorer, etc.
                                            [safename] => no-crank-low-state-of-battery-charge-tsb-91-10-8-for-85-91-bronco-bronco-ii-econoline-f-150-350-series-ranger-86-91-aerostar-88-91-f-super-duty-f47-f-53-f-59-91-explorer-etc-
                                            [parent] => 3
                                            [linkcount] => 0
                                            [level] => 2
                                            [0] => 
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [name] => BATTERY & ISOLATOR
                            [safename] => battery-and-isolator
                            [parent] => 1
                            [linkcount] => 0
                            [level] => 1
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [name] => GENERAL INFORMATION
                            [safename] => general-information
                            [parent] => 1
                            [linkcount] => 0
                            [level] => 1
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => AUDIO AND VIDEO
            [safename] => audio-and-video
            [parent] => 0
            [linkcount] => 0
            [level] => 0
            [0] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [name] => BODY
            [safename] => body
            [parent] => 0
            [linkcount] => 0
            [level] => 0
            [0] => 
        )
    )
)
```

Could someone help me figure out how I would modify my function to build a single dimensional array?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: remove `[]` from your variable `$cat_array3[]` simply use `$cat_array3 = cat_array($cat_id, $level+1);` because you are calling `cat_array()` in  `$cat_array3[]`, there is no need to use '[]' as you are already making an array in `$cat_array` just above `$cat_array3[]`

Comment: Thank you for your help, Manjeet.  I tried making the modification as instructed, but when I did, print_r on $cat_array began returning completely blank.

Comment: `print_r($cat_array3)` before array merge in condition ..

Comment: Using cat_array3[]: http://www.codesend.com/view/158e7dd8b6b49b8caf21b1b73c52f77e/ and using cat_array3: http://www.codesend.com/view/b7c5cb67cb1b373c60ae6405feb71242/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
function cat_array($parent, $level){
    $go = 1;
    global $link;
    if(!ISSET($cat_array)){
        $cat_array = array();
    }
    $q_cats = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = '$parent' ORDER BY name ASC";
    $r_cats = mysqli_query ($link, $q_cats) or die('Catastrophic failure [Super secret code 95162]');
    $num_cats=mysqli_num_rows($r_cats);
    if($num_cats != 0){
        while ($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($r_cats)) {
            $cat_id = $row_cats['id'];
            $name = $row_cats['name'];
            $safename = $row_cats['safename'];
            $parent = $row_cats['parent'];
            $catcounter = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS id FROM links WHERE category = '$cat_id'");
            $catnum = mysqli_fetch_array($catcounter);
            $catcount = number_format($catnum["id"]);

            $cat_array1[] = array("id"=>$cat_id, "name"=>$name, "safename"=>$safename, "parent"=>$parent, "linkcount"=>$catcount, "level"=>$level);

            $cat_array = array_merge($cat_array, $cat_array1);

            /* This is supposed to use the function again inside this loop to find the children of the current row */
            $cat_array3 = cat_array($cat_id, $level+1);

            if(ISSET($cat_array3) AND !empty($cat_array3)){
                $cat_array = array_merge($cat_array, $cat_array3);
            }

        }

    }
    return $cat_array;
}
```